# What base_name parameter do I need in my route to make this Django API work?

Tags: python, django, rest

I am building a Django application that exposes a REST API by which users can query my application's models. I'm following the instructions [**here**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart#testing-our-api).

My Route looks like this in myApp's url.py:

```
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()    router.register(r'myObjects/(?P<id>\d+)/?$', views.MyObjectsViewSet)
url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
```

My Model looks like this:

```
class MyObject(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
```

My Serializer looks like this:

```
class MyObjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyObject
    fields = ('id', 'name',)
```

My Viewset looks like this:

```
class MyObjectsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def retrieve(self,request,pk=None):
        queryset = MyObjects.objects.get(pk=pk).customMyObjectList()

        if not queryset:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            serializer = MyObjectSerializer(queryset)
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

When I hit /api/myObjects/60/ I get the following error:

> `base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.model` or `.queryset` attribute.

I understand from [**here**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers) that I need a base_name parameter on my route. But from the docs, it is unclear to me what that value of that base_name parameter should be. Can someone please tell me what the route should look like with the base_name?

Comment: A similar question (made also by @Saquib Ali) was answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108636/how-to-build-a-django-rest-api-that-returns-a-custom-list-of-models) addressing the same problem.

Answer (score 47):

Try doing this in your urls.py. The third parameter 'Person' can be anything you want.

```
router.register(r'person/food', views.PersonViewSet, 'Person')
```

Comment: and then how what should I type into my browser as the URL to hit that API?

Comment: @SaqibAli it would be 127.0.0.1:8000/person/food.

Comment: @EricLee can you explain why is this happening? Thank you

Comment: @palafox_e The default router uses the queryset defined in the serializer to determine the basename. The basename designates the start of the urls generated by the router. If the queryset is not set as a ViewSet attribute, the router throws up its hands in protest without trying to find queryset in functions. Specifying 'Person' means the internal view_name's will start with 'Person', but the url's are still specified by the first argument
Check this out for more: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#usage

Comment: This answer doesnt explain anything

Answer (score 38):

Let me explain, why we need an **base_name** in the first place and then let's go into the possible value of **base_name**.

If you ever used the Django urls **without** the rest-framework (DRF) before, you would've specified it like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'myObjects/(?P<id>\d+)/?$', views.MyObjectsListView.as_view(), name='myobject-list'),
    url(r'myObjects/(?P<id>\d+)/?$', views.MyObjectsDetailView.as_view(), name='myobject-detail'),
]
```

Here, if you see, there is a **name** parameter which used to identify the url in the **current** namespace (which is app).

This is exactly what django-rest-framework trying to do automatically, since the **drf** knows whether the view is **list** or **detail** (because of viewset). it just needs to append some **prefix** to differentiate the urls. That's the purpose of **base_name** (prefix).

In most scenario, you can give the **url** or **resource name** as **base_name**. In your case, **base_name=myobject**. DRF will generate **base_name + view_type** as the *name* parameter like **myobject_list** & **myobject_detail**.

**Note**: Usually, **base_name** will be *automatically* obtained from the **queryset** field (from view), since it's same for all view types in a viewset. But if you specify, **get_queryset** method instead of **queryset**, it possibly means you've different queryset for different view types (like list, detail). So, DRF will ask you to specify a common **base_name** for all the view types for a resource.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe you just need to set the `base_name` parameter for your router with the name of the object: `MyObject`, in your case.

```python
router.register(r'myObjects/(?P<id>\d+)/?$', views.MyObjectsViewSet, base_name="MyObject")
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#Usage

Comment: Stupidly strange how the docs use `basename` rather than `base_name`.

Comment: It appears the `base_name` argument was renamed to `basename` at some point between versions 3.10.3 and 3.11.0

Answer (score 4):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22114793/1545278) is a useful answer, read for the details.

**tl;dr**

It is used as the base name of the generated URL patterns (e.g., 'myobject-detail' or 'myobject-list').

Comment: but why is it necessary to have base name for generated url patterns?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution might be to use a [ModelViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets#modelviewset) which will derive the basename automatically from the model.

Just make sure and tell it which model to use:

> Because ModelViewSet extends GenericAPIView, you'll normally need to
>   provide at least the queryset and serializer_class attributes, or the
>   model attribute shortcut.

Comment: This is really hard and confusing. Can you just tell me based on my code above what that parameter base_name should be? I don't want to use MovelViewSet because I am not using querysets. I'm doing something more complicated by calling customMyObjectsList().

Answer (score 2):

simply mention this,

```
queryset = MyObjects.objects.all()
```

like this,

```
class MyObjectsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = MyObjects.objects.all()
```

in your corresponding Viewset in views.py instead of mentioning under

def retrieve()...

its worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have two functions in your views.py to query a bunch of employees.
One to query just the name(employeenameviewset) and other to query addresses also(employeeinfoviewset).
Then in your urls.py, add like so:

```py
router.register(r'employee_names', views.employeenameviewset, basename="employees")
router.register(r'employee_details', views.employeeinfoviewset, basename="employees")
```

Using the same basename, the rest of the url will be created automatically by Django like it does in case of URL Conf. In fact this is based on URLConf.