# Register your Django router

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

When I use `route.register` without `base_name` like;

`route.register(r'codes', SmsCodeViewset)`

An error occurred;

`AssertionError: basename argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a .queryset attribute.`

When I use `route.register(r'codes', SmsCodeViewset, bose_name="")` there is no error, may I ask why?

Comment: here is an explanation; [why we need base_name?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50382141/10170918).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was checking my endpoints and I don't have base name in any of them.

```
from app import views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'states', views.StateSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]


class StateSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = State.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StateSerializer
```

Comment: I forgot to add `base_name=""`

Answer (score 0):

we should provide base name to the route when we add it like below

```
router.register(
    r'codes',
    SmsCodeViewset,
    base_name='sms-code',
)
```